# Regex to match N number of digits ignoring break lines only

Tags: java, regex

I need to build a regex in Java that matches N number of digits ignoring Line Breaks.
Please see the example below:

Here is string

```
1234567
891011234
```

I found a solution asking to do this way:

```
(\d\D*){16}
```

It doesn't work because it would match this>

```
1234567smth
891011234
```

Or even match if I have a White Space instead of "smth", and I don't want this..

Please notice that the line break can be in any part of the sequence of digits

So the expression should match this also:

```
123
4567891011234
```

Thank you

Comment: First remove linebreak (you can use `string.replaceAll("\\R","")`and then on result try to find match for 16 digits.

Comment: Other solution could be using regex like `"(\\d\\R*){16}"` to also include linebreaks in match, but approach from previous comment feels more natural IMO (assuming you are only interested in digits).

Comment: Is there a *maximum* of 16 digits - ie would `123456789\n123456789` match  on the first 16 digits? Must the target start at the start of a line?

Comment: @Pshemo Thank you! Both of your approaches help me.
I don't know how I didn't find it anywhere ... maybe doing the wrong search =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, which match 16 digits, but allows any number of newlines within the number:

```
str.matches("(\\d\\R*){16}")
```

fyi, `\R` means "any Unicode linebreak sequence"

To allow at most 1 newline within the digits, change `*` to `?`.

---

```
"1234567\n891011234".matches("(\\d\\R*){16}") // true

"1234567\n8910112349999".matches("(\\d\\R*){16}") // false
"1234567\n891011234foo".matches("(\\d\\R*){16}") // false
"1234567\n89101123".matches("(\\d\\R*){16}") // false
```

Comment: You could have let Pshemo know that he should post an answer rather than posting his solution yourself. Besides, this solution has a flaw: if there is a line break at the start, there will be no match. The solution is `str.matches("\\R*(?:\\d\\R*){16}")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew based on OP's question, I disagree about the leading newline being a requirement in the solution, but thanks for the input. As for Pshemo, I was already where he was before reading his comment, but out of courtesy I waited half an hour or so to allow him to post an answer, and when he didn't I posted what I had already crafted.